# javascript variable and scriptlet value is not matching

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, scriptlet

I am trying to match javascript variable value with value taken from scriptlet in jsp but even value are same I am not getting result true.

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a == <%=Constants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE%>);
```

Here value of Constants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE is "1" [String type] but I am getting console output as false.

Comment: console.log(a == ... ) is this Java or JavaScript ?

Comment: @Stultuske It's Java emitting JavaScript; see the JSP tag?

Comment: firefox firebug javascript debugger.

Comment: What does this line look like when you View Source in the browser?

Comment: @immibis I assumed it was Java. I also assume people who start working with servlets to understand the difference between == and equals.

Comment: it always returns false in console output.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat : please learn the basics. That is not how you compare the value of objects correctly.

Comment: @Stultuske thanks for the suggestion. Do you have a better solution to match javascript value to a constants define in java class. That will be more helpful than your suggestion.

Comment: @Stultuske about which equals method you was talking about in javascript ?

Comment: That's why I asked which language it was. the only response I got was "it's Java" .

Comment: I didn't said it is java only .. please see the tag attached with question.

Comment: What does this line look like when you View Source in the browser?

Comment: @Stultuske Well this is a comparison in JavaScript, so...

Comment: @immibis .. Issue resolved and I already accepted the answer given by someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
    console.log(a == "<%=Constants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE%>");

Comment: Please try assigning scriptlet value to javascript var and then try to compare both javascript vars. Before comparing, plz check both javascript vars should output same value.

Comment: Hi There was fault in my code. Now it is working :) .. accepting the answer .. thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` and compare like below:

```
console.log(a == parseInt(<%=Constants.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE%>));
```

Comment: thanks for answer but javascript does not have strict type check so 1 == "1" are same as 1 == 1 so it is not helping. :(